# Java AppletContext and showDocument() method

Tags: java, applet

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.applet.*;
    import java.net.*;
    /*<applet code=CodeBase width=300 height=300>
    </applet>*/
    public class CodeBase extends Applet
    {
      String sn,br;
      URL url;

    public void start()
    {
     AppletContext ac=getAppletContext();
     url=getCodeBase();
     try{
            ac.showDocument(new URL(url+"a.html"));
    System.out.println("Hello");
   // ac.showDocument(new URL("D:Java Programs//Applet//a.html"));
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e)
     {
        showStatus("Url not found");
    }

    }

    }
```

This code does not show the document of the `a.html` in applet. When we use `AppletContext.showDocument()` method then it display the document at the specified URL, but it not worked.

Answer (score 0):

As a first suggestion, change:

```
ac.showDocument(new URL(url+"a.html"));
```

To:

```
ac.showDocument(new URL(url,"a.html"));
```

But even better, add some sanity checking to the before/after. Something like:

```
URL urlPlus = new URL(url+"a.html");
System.out.println(urlPlus);
URL urlComma = new URL(url,"a.html");
System.out.println(urlComma);
// ...
```

That last part is what I refer to as 'sanity check debugging'.  It is easier to inspect with an IDE that has a debugger, but failing that use the principle *"When in doubt, **print out!**"*

Comment: both print same valueand output is same

Comment: What is the copy/pasted output?  Please imagine I'm not looking over your shoulder at your PC, or psychic.  More details are better than less.